# Creating pointer-to-pointer using malloc

Tags: c, pointers

The code is

```
char** p = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char **) * size); //Where size is some valid value.
p[1] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
```

Is the above code fine?

My understanding is

```
p -> +---------+
     0 char*   + -> {c,o,d,e,\0}
     +---------+

     +---------+
     1 char*   + -> {t,o,a,d,\0} //The assignment of these values is not shown in the code.
     +---------+
```

So we should instead write

```
char** p = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * size);
```

Am I correct?

And is p[0] means *(p + 1) where p+1 will point to "toad" so "toad" will be returned?

Comment: You've tagged this C++ but you are using C notation. If you're really using C++ then you should use new[] rather than malloc, otherwise, retag it as C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a general rule, the '*-ness' of the thing you take the size of inside the malloc call should be 1 '*' less than the pointer receiving the malloc'ed memory.

for instance:

```
char * p = malloc(sizeof(char) * somesize);
```

and

```
char ** p = malloc(sizeof(char *) * somesize);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should `malloc()` `sizeof(char*)` since you intend to store `char*` in the array.

In most cases `sizeof(char **)` will be equal to `sizeof(char *)` so the initial code will work too but you really shouldn't rely on this - it's not absolutely portable and such code is confusing.

`p[0]` means `*(p + 0)`, not `(*p + 1)`. `p[1]` would mean `*(p + 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're basically allocating an array of char* here, of size `size`. `sizeof(char *)` should indeed be used instead of `sizeof(char **)`, but it won't change anything in practice since a pointer is always the same size.

p[0] means *p, I assume you meant p[1] means *(p + 1), which is correct.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I meant to write p[1] but wrote p[0].

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. You are correct that the first allocation should use `sizeof( char * )` but since pointers and pointers to pointers have the same size, it won't matter.

But `p[0]` points to the buffer holding "code" while `p[1]` points to the buffer holding "toad". The code is allocating an array of pointers and then filling in the *second* element of the array while leaving the first uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct.  It should be

```
char** p = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
```

As for your last question, I don't quite follow.  p[0] means *(p+0). p[1] means *(p+1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should write

```
char** p = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * size);
```

But no, `p[0]` means `*(p + 0)` where `p+0` will point to `"code"` so `"code"` will be returned.

If you want "toad", use `p[1]`, which means `*(p + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I always do it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
pointer = malloc(ELEMENTS * sizeof *pointer);
/* check if pointer is NULL */
```

In your case that becomes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char** p = malloc(sizeof *p * size); //Where size is some valid value.
/* check if p is NULL */
p[1] = malloc(sizeof *(p[1]) * 30);
/* check if p[1] is NULL */
```

**Note:** In C, the return value of malloc should not be cast! `void *` is perfectly acceptable to assign to any other pointer type. *In C++ it might be different.*